# Image Gallery code for self display: in C# for android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I would like to ask some help for Gallery App for Android,
I used Visual studio 2019 with C#, I have managed to make code 2 buttons "Next" and "Previous"
But with "Start" I am not able to code it for self display pictures and slide show:
Please find the whole code here:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
namespace Gallery
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
int[] imageTab;
int counter = 0;
Button btnPREVIOUS, btnNEXT, btnSTART;
ImageView imageView;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

btnPREVIOUS = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnPREVIOUS);
btnNEXT = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNEXT);
btnSTART = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSTART);
imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
imageTab = new int[4];
imageTab[0] = Resource.Drawable.img1;
imageTab[1] = Resource.Drawable.img2;
imageTab[2] = Resource.Drawable.img3;
imageTab[3] = Resource.Drawable.img4;

btnNEXT.Click += ButtonClicked;
btnPREVIOUS.Click += ButtonClicked;
btnSTART.Click += ButtonClicked;

}

private void ButtonClicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (timer.Enabled)
{
           
btnSTART.Text = "Start Slideshow";
// initialize it in the constructor to fire every 2s
timer = new Timer(2000);
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;

}
else
{
btnSTART.Text = "Stop Slideshow";
timer.Stop();

}

}

private void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button btn = (Button)sender;
switch (btn.Id)
{
case (Resource.Id.btnNEXT):
{
if (counter < imageTab.Length - 1) counter++;
else counter = 0;
imageView.SetImageResource(imageTab[counter]);
}
break;
case (Resource.Id.btnPREVIOUS):
                {
if (counter > 0) counter--; else counter = 
imageTab.Length - 1;
imageView.SetImageResource(imageTab[counter]);
}
break;
}
}
}
}
```

[I am missing this that one with red encircled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwbJ7.png)

Comment: it's unclear what your question is.  Do you want to know how to write a slideshow function?  Generally you would use a System.Timers.Timer that updates the image every time it fires

Comment: @Jason, I need to write the core to display the pictures once I click on the button,

Comment: You already have code to display pictures.  Does that work?  How is the "Start" button different than the other buttons?  If you want an automated slideshow see my earlier comment.  Do you know how to use a C# timer?  You have to be specific about your problem if you want us to help you.  See [ask] for guidance on writing a good question.

Comment: @Jason , I have already edited the question please kindly check the code which work partially, 2 buttons(Next and Previous) are working correctly but the button(start) which makes slideshow doesn't work, I need it to click and then the pictures will display themselves and stop when I click again to the button (Start)

Comment: please format your code so it's readable.  And I've mentioned `Timer` twice - do you know what that is?  If not, have you looked it up in the C# docs?

Comment: Yes I have checked in C# document but I wasn't able to use it in my code, I need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create a timer

```
using System.Timers;

// declare it in your class
Timer timer;

// initialize it in the constructor to fire every 2s
timer = new Timer(2000);
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.AutoReset = true;
```

then create the `Elapsed` handler

```
private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // increment counter and display image
   counter++;
   if (counter >= imageTab.Length) counter = 0;
   imageView.SetImageResource(imageTab[counter]);
}
```

finally, toggle the timer when your button is clicked

```
private void ToggleTimer(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
   If (timer.Enabled)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    } else {
        timer.Start();
    }
   }
```

and assign it to your button

```
btnSTART.Click += ToggleTimer;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate your time and help, your solution works tremendously(Slideshow works now). Now I am trying to implement the way to stop slideshow. When I click again on the button it doesn't stop slideshow

Comment: is it setting Enabled to false?  That should work.  Alternately, you can use the Stop() method

Comment: I tried without success, sorry that I am still Junior, but you can assist again. Below you may find my code below:

Comment: I have edited the main question and added Start Button, if can help to code stop, I may appreciate

Comment: See my edit.  You have your logic backwards.  There is also no reason to reinitialize the timer.

Comment: now it works tremendously, it is only from your help that I could make it successfully. I appreciate your skills in .NET C#, I have another post for Tic Tac Toe, maybe you will be helping as well.